# How to save the user email address into 2 different textboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically I have 2 textboxes; I would like whatever the user types into the **email** textbox to be saved into the **name** textbox as well.

Basically saving the email address in 2 places. I’m new to MVC any examples would be good, cheers.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => registerModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => registerModel.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: On controller method just use: `registerModel.Name=registerModel.Email;`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the extra textbox? Just save the value of the 1st one in both properties when you save it in the POST method.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the code is on cshtml page. I can't assign the values like registerModel.Name=registerModel.Email; What is the correct syntax

Comment: I'm using this code within a partial View,

Comment: I can’t assign the value within the controller because the validation from the view kicks in first. I don’t know how to remove the validation. The page is a self generated by Umbraco and the validation is buried deep within the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `save` the same values for the both text fields, you can assign same value to both on post function, there is no need for an additional text field.

But if you want to display same value for both text box while typing on one text box. Then try following javascript.

```
$("#Name").keyup(function(){

   var Names = $("#Name").val();
   $("#Email").val(Names);

})
```